# list index out of range in calculation of nodal distance

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a small task in which I have to find the distance between two nodes. Each node has X and Y coordinates which can be seen below.

```
node_number  X_coordinate  Y_coordinate
0             0             1             0
1             1             1             1
2             2             1             2
3             3             1             3
4             4             0             3
5             5             0             4
6             6             1             4
7             7             2             4
8             8             3             4
9             9             4             4
10           10             4             3
11           11             3             3
12           12             2             3
13           13             2             2
14           14             2             1
15           15             2             0
```

For the purpose I mentioned above, I wrote below code,

```
X1_coordinate = df['X_coordinate'].tolist()
Y1_coordinate = df['Y_coordinate'].tolist()
node_number1 = df['node_number'].tolist()    
nodal_dist = []
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(node_number1)):
        dist = math.sqrt((X1_coordinate[i+1] - X1_coordinate[i])**2 + (Y1_coordinate[i+1] - Y1_coordinate[i])**2)
        nodal_dist.append(dist)
```

I got the error

```
list index out of range
```

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong and what should I change to get the answer.

Comment: The index is zero-based and the `len()` starts counting from 1. So you need `len(x) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Indexing starts at zero, so the last element in the list has an index that is one less than the number of elements in that list. But the `len()` function gives you the number of elements in the list (in other words, it starts counting at 1), so you want the range of your loop to be `len(node_number1) - 1` to avoid an -off-by-one error.

Answer (score 0):

The problems should been in this line

```
 dist = math.sqrt((X1_coordinate[i+1] - X1_coordinate[i])**2 + (Y1_coordinate[i+1] - Y1_coordinate[i])**2)
```

the  `X1_coordinate[i+1]` and the ] `Y1_coordinate[i+1]]` go out of range on the last number call.